# How to use ARRAYFORMULA in an IFS statement

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

Using IFS with ARRAYFORMULA creates an error saying that the:
"IFS has mismatched range sizes.  Expected row count 1. column count 1......"

`=IFS(A2="A",ARRAYFORMULA(B3:B10),A2="B",ARRAYFORMULA(C3:C10)` create an error on my test page below.  Any help is appreciated.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FsacWMMCptyy0YU_ZwC6d0TUzbeUeIlCzRUTF-gSFcU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). The problem would probably be better described as "how to use `ifs()` in an array formula" rather than the other way around.

Comment: Many thanks to doubleunary for his quick and accurate solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ifs()` function is more picky than the `if()` function when it comes to operand and result dimensions. Use this pattern:

```
=arrayformula( 
  ifs( 
    iferror(B3:B10 / 0, A2) = "A", 
      B3:B10, 
    iferror(C3:C10 / 0, A2) = "B", 
      C3:C10, 
    true, 
      na() 
  ) 
)
```